# Probability Measure vs pmf

Tags: probability

I'm a little confused about the difference between a probability measure and a pmf. I know that if you have an outcome space $S$ ($S=\{H,T\}$ for a coin flip, for example), then we can define a discrete random variable $X$ with domain $S$ such that $X(H)=1$ and $X(T)=0$. Then we can define a pmf $f(x)$ on $\text{Range}(X)=\{0,1\}$. My question is, do you define the probability measure on the outcome space $S=\{H,T\}$ or the $\text{Range}(X)=\{0,1\}$? My book says $f(x)$ is defined to mean $P(X=x)$, where x is an element of $\text{Range}(X)$, so that makes me think that a probability measure is defined on $\text{Range}(X)$ and not on the outcome space. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different probability measures in this setting:

- The "universe" probability measure $\Pr$ on the outcome space
- The probability measure $P_X$ on $\{0,1\}$ induced by the random variable $X$, which is usually called the distribution of $X$.

They are linked together by the relation $P_X(x) = \Pr\{X=x\}$ for $x \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: In your definition, $P_X(x)$ seems to be the definition of the p.m.f. for $X$. Is that correct? So, the pmf is indeed a probability measure.